# Как нарисовать круг используя только линии в tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Через функцию `create_oval` легко, но линиями не получается

```
import turtle

n = 0
for s in range(5):
    i = 0
    while i < 361:
        turtle.width(2)
        turtle.fd(0.5 + n)
        turtle.left(1) 
        i += 1
        n += 0.5
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-350, -25 - s * 25)
    turtle.pendown()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: import turtlen = 0
for s in range(5):
    i = 0
    while i < 361:
        turtle.width(2)
        turtle.fd(0.5 + n)
        turtle.left(1)
        i += 1
    n += 0.5
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-350, -25 - s * 25)
    turtle.pendown()

turtle.exitonclick() вот например  я с  помощью  черепашки делаю круг маленькими линиями

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
import math
from tkinter import *


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.w = Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg='black')
        self.w.draw_regular_polygon((200,200), 100, 15, 0, outline='red') 
        self.w.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
    def _draw_regular_polygon(self, center, radius, n, angle, **kwargs):
        angle -= (math.pi/n)
        coord_list = [[center[0] + radius * math.sin((2*math.pi/n) * i - angle),
            center[1] + radius * math.cos((2*math.pi/n) * i - angle)] for i in range(n)]
        return self.create_polygon(coord_list, **kwargs)
        
    Canvas.draw_regular_polygon = _draw_regular_polygon
    
    
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Maxim я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Maxim  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

```
import tkinter as tk
from math import cos, sin, radians

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)

x_offset = 200 
y_offset = 200 
radius = 100 

coords = [ (radius * cos(radians(angle)), radius * sin(radians(angle))) for angle in range(360)]

# Замыкаем круг путём добавления первой координаты в конец списка.
# Иначе будет разрыв между последней и первой точкой.
coords.append(coords[0])
for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(coords, coords[1:]):
    canvas.create_line(x_offset + x1, y_offset + y1, x_offset + x2, y_offset + y2, width=3)
```

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]